# Accessing Folders from App's Documents directory through iTunes

Tags: iphone, directory

I have created an iPad application which contains images. I am storing these images under "Test" folder which is created by using the following code into Documents directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test" withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:dict error:nil];
```

And now when I connect my iPad through iTunes, I can see "Test" folder in iTunes.

My problem is I want to add some images into that folder through iTunes.
How can i do this?? Do I need to give some permissions at the time of creating Directory??

Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add (or view) files in a folder in the Documents folder in iTunes - you can only download it to your computer and then access the files in it.

Uploading via iTunes is only possible directly on top level to the documents folder.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using iExplorer ... it's a program that allows you to manually add/remove files from your devices ... even from individual apps.